# Issue with timezone with time.strftime

Tags: python, ubuntu, time, timezone

I've been using [blockhosts](http://www.aczoom.com/blockhosts) for some time now, and it's been great so far. I recently updated Ubuntu to 10.10, and I started to see some erratic behaviour. Upon a closer inspection, I noticed a bunch of errors in /var/log/blockhosts.log:

`ERROR:  failed to parse date for ip 188.17.155.25, using now value:
   time data '2010-11-01 03:04:02 AMT' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'`

The fact of the timezone appearing as "AMT" (Armenian time) is strange. My timezone is set as:

`$ cat /etc/timezone

Europe/Amsterdam`

I took a look at the code of `blockhosts.py` where the date is handled and checked, and I saw that is being handled as `time` objects.

The following code shows the problem:

```
import time

now = time.time()

str1 = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z', time.localtime())
str2 = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')

print str1
print str2
```

The output is the following:

```
2010-12-06 16:18:47 AMT 
2010-12-06 16:18:47 CET
```

The value of `time.tzname` is `('CET', 'CEST')`, so I'm not sure where the "AMT" is coming from...

Any help will be appreciated!

**Updates:**

From the suggestions in the comments:

- `/etc/localtime` is not a symlink to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Amsterdam`, but they are the same file:

`$ ls -l /etc/localtime

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2917 2010-11-18 09:35 /etc/localtime

$ ls -l /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Amsterdam

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2917 2010-11-11 09:35 /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Amsterdam

$ diff /etc/localtime /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Amsterdam`

- there is no TZ environment variable:

`$ echo $TZ

$ env | grep TZ`

- I logged in as another user and run the script with the same result:

`2010-12-07 11:12:09 AMT

2010-12-07 11:12:09 CET`

Comment: I love python, but datetime sux bigtime.

Comment: Sounds like a possible bug. Set up a new user account on your computer, and see if you can replicate it there. If so, try filing a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-defaults/+bugs

Comment: /etc/timezone normally isn't the place you set your timezone. /etc/localtime needs to be a symlink to the correct timezone in /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Amsterdam -- thats step one. The second step is to make sure it's getting picked up correctly. You can check this with 'date' (regular old unix command), also verify you don't have an environment variable named TZ that has anything different than what you're trying to use. You should log out and log back in to ensure that /etc/timezone is being picked up correctly by locale / your shell.. Then try your python code.

Answer (score 0):

The time module doesn't do much than call the unix C API calls, so I would suspect your configuration first of all.

That said, `time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z', time.localtime())` and `time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')` should be equivalent, as time.localtime() is the default for the argument, so how those are different is beyond me.

Comment: I agree with you here, this is one of the things I realized. I can't locate any fault in the configuration, as I added to the edits above. Any other clues?

Comment: No, that's all normal. Strange. I'm now leaning towards it being a really, really, really strange bug, possibly even in in libc. :) Reporting it might help, but there are a *lot* of bugs so don't hold your breath.